# Error in Sql Query - Can't find the solution

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm having big troubles to find the error in my sql query.

```
CREATE FUNCTION freeSeats(bookingID INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(30)
BEGIN
DECLARE numberBooked INT ;
DECLARE status VARCHAR(30);

SELECT count(*) FROM passenger WHERE Booking IN(SELECT Id FROM booking WHERE
Flight = (SELECT Flight FROM booking WHERE Id = bookingID)) INTO numberBooked;

IF (numberBooked > 59) THEN SET status =”No free seats”;
ELSE SET status =”OK”;
END IF;

RETURN status;
END;
```

I get this error message:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'free seats”; ELSE SET status =”OK”; END IF;
>
> RETURN status; END' at line 10

I would appreciate some help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using the wrong quotes?

Comment: Yes, i noticed that now. I wrote the queries in word and then copied them to the terminal, stupid of me :/

Comment: Yea Word likes to add screwy characters to everything, it's the last thing you'd want to use to write code.  Did that fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

- don't for get to change the `DELIMITER`
- use single quotes

example,

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION freeSeats(bookingID INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(30)
BEGIN
    DECLARE numberBooked INT ;
    DECLARE status VARCHAR(30);

    SET numberBooked =
    (
    SELECT count(*) 
    FROM passenger 
    WHERE Booking IN 
        (   SELECT  Id 
            FROM    booking 
            WHERE   Flight = (SELECT Flight FROM booking WHERE Id = bookingID)
        ) 
    );

    IF (numberBooked > 59) THEN 
        SET status = 'No free seats';
    ELSE 
        SET status = 'OK';
    END IF;

    RETURN status;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```